# How to embed image in a ListView in code behind?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a ListView created in XAML and bound to a list in C# code behind.

I am trying to insert an embedded image into the ListView from C# but not sure how I'm failing here.

The image property is set as an `EmbeddedResource`

Here is my XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Status}" TextColor="Gray"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button Text="Follow"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is my C# code behind

```
public ListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Image embeddedImage = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromResource("App2.Images.image.jpg")
            };

            listView.ItemsSource = new List<Contact>
            {
                new Contact {Name = "Name", Status = "Hi!", ImageUrl = new Image{ Source = ImageSource.FromResource("App2.Images.cat.jpg")} },
                new Contact {Name = "John", Status = "Bye!" },
                new Contact {Name = "Jennifer"}
            };
        }
```

Here is my Contact model

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Image ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Source = ImageSource.FromResource("WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg", typeof(xxx).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)` .Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I've tried adding that in as well, still the picture doesn't show.

Comment: `ImageUrl` should be a string with the image/resource name

Comment: @Jason like this? `public string ImageUrl { get; set;}` `new Contact {Name = "Name", Status = "Hi!", ImageUrl = "App2.Images.image.jpg"},` unless i'm writing it wrong, this still doesn't show the image

Comment: please read the docs on using local images - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: or embedded images - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images